# npm loads not only my packages decleard in package.json

Tags: javascript, npm

I'm working on a small project using npm, bower and grunt.
When I do an "npm install" on my PC, its loading a lot wired stuff (see screenshot).
But when I do the same on my MBA its loading only my declared packages:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-grunticon": "^2.2.2"
  }
}
```

[image: node_modules folder]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

npm3 (which is used by default since Nodev5) flattens the dependency tree. You may still be using npm2 (which doesn't do that) on the other system.

From the [changelog](https://github.com/npm/npm/releases/tag/v3.0.0):

> #### Flat, flat, flat!
>
> Your dependencies will now be installed maximally flat. Insofar as is possible, all of your dependencies, and their dependencies, and THEIR dependencies will be installed in your project's node_modules folder with no nesting. You'll only see modules nested underneath one another when two (or more) modules have conflicting dependencies.

Comment: I 've read about the changed behavior in version 3. But it should only load dependencies written in package.json, isn't it?

Comment: Of course, that didn't change. But your dependencies also have dependencies. Please read the quote again. It's literally in there.